# Conditionally change label on calendar primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to change the label conditionally on Primefaces calendar . I have the below code

```
<p:calendar value="#{requestMBean.requestTO.startDate}"  id="startDate" 
label="#{requestMBean.requestTO.requestType eq 'SINGLEDAY'}?#{msg['wfmt.label.request.fromDate']}:#{msg['wfmt.label.request.visitingDate']}}"
pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"/>
```

When the validation fails I expect to see only one label . But I get "Please enter : true?fromDate:visitingDate" .

How can I conditionally render only one label ?

Comment: your el is not correct. #{requestMBean.requestTO.requestType eq 'SINGLEDAY'}?#{msg['wfmt.label.request.fromDate']}:#{msg['wfmt.label.request.visitingDate']}} 
Change it like #{ condition ? true:false}

Comment: How should I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#{requestMBean.requestTO.requestType eq 'SINGLEDAY'}?#{msg['wfmt.label.request.fromDate']}:#{msg['wfmt.label.request.visitingDate']}} is wrong.
```

Change it to `"#{condition ? true statement : false statement}"` if you want you can use () for code readability.

**Edited**

```
#{requestMBean.requestTO.requestType eq 'SINGLEDAY' ? msg['wfmt.label.request.fromDate'] : msg['wfmt.label.request.visitingDate']}
```

Comment: accept my answer if it is correct.

Comment: #{requestMBean.requestTO.requestType eq 'SINGLEDAY'?#{msg['wfmt.label.request.fromDate']}:#{msg['wfmt.label.request.visitingDate']}} . If I add this I see EL parser error

Comment: why you are using multiple # it is not required. see my ans edited